# Display a value dynamically on JSP

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I have a table and I'm fetching the values from it through Java. I wanted to display the values on the JSP page such that when a dropdown option is selected the corresponding value should be painted on the JSP page. How can I do it ?

Comment: Can we see [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far and what problems you are having with your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

You must post some of your code to see what you need to list, but simplest way to show custom objects, will be something like this:

```
<form:select path="selectedItem.value" type="text" name="name"  >
    <form:options items="${bean.listOfItems}" itemValue="value" />
</form:select>
```

**NOTE**: *To fit the example: Your `public List<MyObject> listOfItems` and `public MyObject selectedItem` must exist in the bean with valid `getters` and `setters`. Objects of class `MyObject` must have attribute `public xxx value` to fit this example.*